# React Native expo with SQLite

Tags: javascript, sql, react-native, sqlite, expo

I am working on a React Native app (expo) for a school project, but I am stuck. I am relatively new to react when it comes to integrating it with SQL. I have made an SQLite database to select some data from in my app.

I tried something like this:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { SafeAreaView, StyleSheet, Text, FlatList, Image, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import HeaderComponent from '../components/Header';
import Card from '../components/Card'; 
import * as SQLite from 'expo-sqlite';
import { FileSystem } from 'expo';

// load DB for expo
// Add this code on your app.js

global.db = SQLite.openDatabase(
  {
    name: 'traclo_db.db',
    location: 'default',
    createFromLocation: '~SQLite.db',
  },
  () => { },
  error => {
    console.log("ERROR: " + error);
  }
);

db.transaction((tx) => {
  tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM tbl_brand', [], (tx, results) => {
  console.log("Query completed");

   
  var len = results.rows.length;
  for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    let row = results.rows.item(i);
    console.log(`BrandName: ${row.brand_name}, Score: ${row.brand_score}`);
  }
  });
});

//view for the homescreen
export default function Home({ navigation }) {
  const [
    selectedIndex,
    setSelectedIndex
  ] = React.useState(0);

  return (
    //this 'SafeAreaView' is required to render it safe on the screen, within the margins
    <SafeAreaView forceInset={{ bottom: 'always' }} style={style.container}>
        <HeaderComponent 
            selectedIndex={selectedIndex} 
            setSelectedIndex={setSelectedIndex}
        />
        <Card
            BrandName="Adidas"
            Score="83"
            Logo={require('../assets/Adidas.png')}
        />   
      </SafeAreaView>
  );
}

//style props of the header
const style = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#ffffff'
  },
})
```

If this worked I wouldn't be posting a question here :) I want to open the database and render a card component for all the records in the table tbl_brand, but I have really no idea how to do that. Can you help me please, or do you have some ideas for this? :)